# Заблокировать скроллинг в момент очистки и заполнения данными

Tags: android, listview

Всем здрасте, столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть `ListView` заполненный некоторыми данными, по нажатии на кнопку данные после парсинга обновляются. Дело в том, что пока новых данных нет я должен видеть старые. Я нажимаю на кнопку и в это время быстро скроллю старые результаты поиска, приложение падает.
В общем надо сделать так чтоб в момент очистки и заполнения данными скроллинг как-то блокировался.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено:

```
lvMain.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (check_2!=0) {
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```